# Generate random number with Python GUI (beginner)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

New to python. Can't figure out how to generate a random number, between 1000000 and 9999999, and to display in the 'Receipt No.' column after I press 'show details'.

Here's my code:

```
########################################################################
###  This program is so julie can track items hired from her store   ###
########################################################################

#import tkinter so i can use GUI
from tkinter import *

#quit subroutine
def quit():
    main_window.destroy()

#print details of all the items
def print_hire_details ():
    name_count = 0
    #Create the column headings for "Print Details"
    Label(main_window, font=("Helvetica 10 bold"),text="Row").grid(column=0,row=7)
    Label(main_window, font=("Helvetica 10 bold"),text="Name").grid(column=1,row=7)
    Label(main_window, font=("Helvetica 10 bold"),text="Item Hired").grid(column=2,row=7)
    Label(main_window, font=("Helvetica 10 bold"),text="No. Items Hired").grid(column=3,row=7)
    Label(main_window, font=("Helvetica 10 bold"),text="Receipt No.").grid(column=4,row=7)

    #add each item in the list into its own row
    while name_count < counters['total_entries'] :
        Label(main_window, text=name_count).grid(column=0,row=name_count+8) 
        Label(main_window, text=(hire_details[name_count][0])).grid(column=1,row=name_count+8)
        Label(main_window, text=(hire_details[name_count][1])).grid(column=2,row=name_count+8)
        Label(main_window, text=(hire_details[name_count][2])).grid(column=3,row=name_count+8)
        name_count +=  1
        counters['name_count'] = name_count
        
#Check the inputs are all valid
def check_inputs ():
    input_check = 0
    Label(main_window, text="               ") .grid(column=2,row=0)
    Label(main_window, text="               ") .grid(column=2,row=1)
    Label(main_window, text="               ") .grid(column=2,row=2)
    Label(main_window, text="               ") .grid(column=2,row=3)
    #Check that Name is not blank, set error text if blank   
    if len(entry_name.get()) == 0 :
        Label(main_window,fg="red", text="Required") .grid(column=2,row=0)
        input_check = 1
    #Check that Item Hired is not blank, set error text if blank     
    if len(entry_item.get()) == 0 :
        Label(main_window,fg="red", text="Required") .grid(column=2,row=1)
        input_check = 1
    #Check the Number of Items is not blank and between 1 and 500, set error text if blank  
    if (entry_hires.get().isdigit()) : 
        if  int(entry_hires.get()) < 1 or  int(entry_hires.get()) > 500:
            Label(main_window,fg="red", text="1-500 only") .grid(column=2,row=2)
            input_check = 1
    else :
        Label(main_window,fg="red", text="1-500 only") .grid(column=2,row=2)
        input_check = 1

    if input_check == 0 : append_name() 

        
            
#add the next item to the list
def append_name ():
    #append each item to its own area of the list
    hire_details.append([entry_name.get(),entry_item.get(),entry_hires.get()])
    #clear the boxes
    entry_name.delete(0,'end')
    entry_item.delete(0,'end')
    entry_hires.delete(0,'end')
    counters['total_entries'] += 1

#delete a row from the list
def delete_row ():
    #find which row is to be deleted and delete it
    del hire_details[int(delete_item.get())]
    counters['total_entries'] -= 1
    name_count = counters['name_count']
    delete_item.delete(0,'end')
    #clear the last item displayed on the GUI
    Label(main_window, text="       ").grid(column=0,row=name_count+7) 
    Label(main_window, text="       ").grid(column=1,row=name_count+7)
    Label(main_window, text="       ").grid(column=2,row=name_count+7)
    Label(main_window, text="       ").grid(column=3,row=name_count+7)
    Label(main_window, text="       ").grid(column=4,row=name_count+7)
    #print all the items in the list
    print_hire_details()

#create the buttons and labels
def setup_buttons():
    #create all the empty and default labels, buttons and entry boxes. Put them in the correct grid position
    Label(main_window, text="Name") .grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=E)
    Label(main_window, text="Item") .grid(column=0,row=1,sticky=E)
    Button(main_window, text="Quit",command=quit,width = 10) .grid(column=4, row=0,sticky=E)
    Button(main_window, text="Append Details",command=check_inputs) .grid(column=3,row=1)
    Button(main_window, text="Print Details", command=print_hire_details, width=10).grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=E)
    Label(main_window, text="No of Items") .grid(column=0,row=2,sticky=E)
    Label(main_window, text="Row #") .grid(column=3,row=2,sticky=E)
    Button(main_window, text="Delete Row",command=delete_row,width = 10) .grid(column=4,row=3,sticky=E)
    Label(main_window, text="               ") .grid(column=2,row=0)



#start the program running
def main():
    #Start the GUI it up
    setup_buttons()
    main_window.mainloop()
    
#create empty list for hire details and empty variable for entries in the list
counters = {'total_entries':0,'name_count':0}
hire_details = []    
main_window =Tk()    
entry_name = Entry(main_window)
entry_name.grid(column=1,row=0)
entry_receipt = Entry(main_window)
entry_item = Entry(main_window)
entry_item.grid(column=1,row=1)
entry_hires = Entry(main_window)
entry_hires.grid(column=1,row=2)
delete_item = Entry(main_window)
delete_item .grid(column=3,row=3)
main()
```

I need a new and different receipt number after the user presses 'append details' (and all other input has been given). But I can't get it display in that column (or any columns). Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Use  namespace import random

Comment: I guess a [web search](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=python+random+number&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english) was not an option? And why dump all the unrelated code here? Please check [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the `random` module.

```
import random

randInt = random.randint(1000000, 9999999)
```

I would also recommend declaring variables for widgets like so:

```
label1 = Label()
```

That way you can re-declare them to show a different number:

```
global label1
label1 = Label(text=randInt)
```